# Question about BIP70 and bitpays recent card top up changes

Tags: blockchain, bitpay, bip70-payment-protocol

Okay so bitpay just sent out an email that outlines some changes to their card top-up process. Apparently, they are implementing BIP70 and I am honestly not very familiar with what exactly that is. I did some research but am still very confused. Also my main question really is will this be compatible with my trezor hardware wallet? I've attached a screenshot of bitpays email. I am hoping one of you knowledgeable crypo devs could help me clarify this and if it's not compatible perhaps you could recommend the best option from here going forward. I really do not want to sacrifice my security of my trezor. [image]